# read_pdf error from tabule for read the pdf files..?

Tags: python, tabula

I use the tabula package for pdf reading ,but here i got these error

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("/tmp/university_exam_results.pdf", output_format="json", pages="all")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_pdf'
```

what can i do for this error .please fix my issue..

Comment: Did you import tabula?

Comment: mm yes i import tabula

Comment: mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$ pip install tabula
Requirement already satisfied: tabula in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tabula)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tabula)
mahendranatarajan@amachu-Inspiron-3558:~$

Answer (score 0):

For Python2, I think you're searching for

```
pip2 install tabula-py
```

And as an example,

```
>>> import tabula
>>> df2 = tabula.read_pdf("https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/raw/master/src/test/resources/technology/tabula/arabic.pdf")
>>> df2
                         مرحباً                 اسمي سلطان
0  انا من ولاية كارولينا الشمال                من اين انت؟
1                          1234                عندي 47 قطط
2                  هل انت شباك؟  اسمي Jeremy في الانجليزية
3      Jeremy is جرمي in Arabic                        NaN
```

Comment: Did you `pip uninstall tabula` to remove the old one?

Comment: shall i remove the old one..?

Comment: i got this error after uninstall tabula "ImportError: No module named tabula
"